# How to keep the forked repo synced to original repo

Tags: git, github, open-source

Github says, `"This branch is 10 commits ahead, 8 commits behind xyz:master"`.

How do I make it even with the master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull `master` into your branch (`say, feature`) then solved "8 commits behind". And if you merge `feature` with `master` then "10 commits ahead" would be solved.

```
# merge 'master' into 'feature' branch (solve '8 commits behind')

$ git fetch
$ git checkout feature 
$ git pull origin master         # pull latest commits of master
$ git push origin HEAD           # update remote/feature

# merge 'feature' into 'master' branch (solve '10 commits ahead')

$ git checkout master            # checkout 'master'  
$ git pull origin master         # sync with origin/master
$ git pull origin feature        # pull latest commits of your branch 'feature'
$ git push origin master         # push to remote/master
```

Comment: this reflects only locally , but i want it to be reflected in my remote fork

Comment: After pulling, push your changes to remote .

Comment: now i am still having This branch is 11 commits ahead of xyz:master.
How do i solve this?

Comment: Have you pulled `your-branch` into `master` and push to remote master? Give `git fetch` command at first.

Comment: yes i did that and one more thing is when i created a pull request its showing all the previous commits that i have done.

Comment: Have your pull req is merged with master? And check if `your branch's last commit` exists on `master` or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132917/discussion-between-anagh-hegde-and-sajib-khan).

Answer (score -2):

Merge the two branches together